# Unable to access/rename/delete directory

Tags: command-line, permissions

When I list files/directories with command `ll | grep 'TM'`

```
ls: cannot access TM: No such file or directory
???????????  ? ?      ?         ?            ? TM
```

I can see `TM` folder is listed but when rename/deleting or accessing, it gives error -

```
rm -rf TM
rm: cannot remove ‘TM’: Is a directory

mv TM TM1
mv: cannot stat ‘TM’: No such file or directory

ls TM
ls: cannot access TM: No such file or directory
```

I cannot perform any action on it. Why could it be so? Also help to understand why user, permission, size, date etc set to `?` for it.

Comment: Add the output of ls -l to your question showing the TM directory.

Comment: Actually `TM` was mounted directory I unmounted it and then can process on it.